# How can I replace the word/number after a pattern, but just one word, not what follow after, through vi or any other tool

Tags: linux, centos, text-processing

I want to change the port number to 0 in multiple scripts, but I want the text after port 0 to stay the same. Is there a way to do that. through vi, I can change the pattern, but not the port numbers because they are all unique. Thanks!

```
local-ip 159.105.100.40 port 5510 remote-ip 152.16.142.104 port 3868
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whith `sed` is simple:

```bsh
$ foo="local-ip 159.105.100.40 port 5510 remote-ip 152.16.142.104 port 3868"
$ echo "$foo" | sed 's/port [0-9]\{1,5\}/port 0/g'
local-ip 159.105.100.40 port 0 remote-ip 152.16.142.104 port 0
```

So

```bsh
# let's suppose that all your scripts are in the same directory
# and have the extension .sh
for file in *.sh; do
  # WARNING: the -i option writes the file
  # so it's better to try first without it
  sed -i 's/port [0-9]\{1,5\}/port 0/g' "$file"
done
```

---

In `vi` you can use the same command:

```
:s/port [0-9]\{1,5\}/port 0/g
```

Or simpler, as [@Quasímodo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/388654/quas%C3%ADmodo) suggest:

```
 :s/port \d\+/port 0/g
```